# Xpath. How to specify a node between two nodes?

Tags: xpath

There may be two possible structures:

1.

```
<c>TTTT</c>
<a>AAAA</a>
<b>BBBB</b>
<c>CCCC</c>
<d>DDDD</d>
<c>CCCC</c>
```

2.

```
<c>TTTT</c>
<a>AAAA</a>
<b>BBBB</b>
<d>DDDD</d>
<c>CCCC</c>
```

How can I select the node `<c>` after `<b>` in first case and if it is the second case, set it null?

Comment: Can you post an example of the xml/html?

Comment: I agree in general - but a sample makes it easier to throw into a tool and test results rather than assuming the users schema and data. Or I am over thinking the question.

Comment: @Geohut Paxic commented before question formatted properly to display the XML sample, just to make the situation clear. Also, "after b" in xpath would be `b/following-sibling::someNode`, it is perfectly possible, although *between 2 nodes* is sometimes not possible

Comment: @har07 thanks har didn't remember that one, and I believe I posted right after it must have been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`following-sibling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) axis for this purpose :

```
//b/following-sibling::*[1][self::c]
```

Brief explanation :

- `b/following-sibling::*[1]`: get *direct sibling* following a `<b>`
- `[self::c]`: check if that sibling is a `<c>` element